# Как правильно закодировать спецсимволы в GET запросе?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Возникла ошибка, когда цикл создавал GEt массив с разных имен материалов, в некоторых был *+* и это потом затормозило всю работу, так как при выводе *+* не отображается совсем. Пробовал PHP urlencode - перехожу по ссылке - такой страницы не существует.

```
var src_red;
function saveOptions(){
    var src2 = '?all=1'
    for(var i = 1; i <= 46; i++){
            if ($('.vozv' + i).hasClass('selt')) { //если элемент выпадающий список
                window['var vozv' + i] = $('.vozv' + i + ' option:selected').text();

            }
            else{ //если инпут
                window['var vozv' + i] = $('.vozv' + i).val();

            }
            src2 = src2 + '&vozv' + i + '=' + window['vozv' + i];

        }
    src_red = src2;
}
```

дальше отправляю на сервер и сохраняю. Есть страница с ссылками в которых имеется GET-запрос, переходя по ссылке все поля должны автоматически заполнятся:

```
 var array;
    function Restore(){
        array = {<?
                foreach ($_GET as $keyk => $valuee) {
                    echo "'".$keyk."':'".$valuee."',";
                }
            ?>};
        for (var i in array){ //перебираю массив *имя: текст*

            if ($('.' + i).hasClass('selt')) {
                $('.'+ i +' option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == array[i]; }).prop('selected', 'true');
            }
            else{
                $('.' + i).val(array[i]);
            }
            $('.' + i).trigger('change');
        }
    }
```

Все работает нормально, пока в имени не появляется какой-то спецсимвол. Его просто не отображает, кто знает как справиться с такой ситуацией?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вашу проблему может решить метод [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeuricomponent)

Comment: спасибо, порылся в интернете и таки использовал этот метод